# How to create a table with composite foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I created the master table with the composite primary key.

parent table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `taskcategory` (
  `SiteID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `TaskID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TaskName` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `TaskDescription` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `IsInbuild` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`TaskID`,`SiteID`)
);
```

when i am trying to create the table with foreign key with the above parent table reference i am getting 'can't create table error no 150' error . help me to do that.

child table structure as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE taskdetails (`SiteID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TaskID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SubtaskID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ScriptName` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `FunctionName` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ButtonName` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `IsInbuild` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`SubtaskID`,`TaskID`,`SiteID`),
                            INDEX (siteid, taskid),
                            FOREIGN KEY (siteid, taskid)
                              REFERENCES taskcategory(siteid, taskid)
                              ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
                            ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

help me to resolve it.

Comment: AFAIK you do not need to have index on columns when they are foreign key.

Comment: @niraj nawanit - I tried without the index too but getting the same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

So when you add an index in the parent table it works (yes, I tested it):

```
CREATE TABLE `taskcategory` (
  `SiteID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `TaskID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TaskName` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `TaskDescription` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `IsInbuild` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`TaskID`,`SiteID`)
  , INDEX (SiteID, TaskID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE taskdetails (`SiteID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TaskID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SubtaskID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ScriptName` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `FunctionName` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ButtonName` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `IsInbuild` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`SubtaskID`,`TaskID`,`SiteID`)
                            ,INDEX (SiteID, TaskID)
                            ,FOREIGN KEY (SiteID, TaskID)
                              REFERENCES taskcategory(SiteID, TaskID)
                              ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
                            ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

You have a primary key on those columns already (which means there's an implicit index), but the **order of the columns is important**!

Comment: Also you may have to adhere to case-sensitiveness, in case you are using linux

Answer (score 0):

Your table definition of taskcategory lacks the ENGINE=InnoDB clause, and probably this is not your system's default. Foreign key relations can only be set up between InnoDB tables.

Comment: This doesn't raise an error, any relationships are simply ignored in MyISAM.